# How do I set the background color of a widget like combobox or double spin box?

Tags: qt, qcombobox, qspinbox

I am trying to set the background color for a double spin box, and I am not sure what function I should use.

I saw some function called `SetBackgroundRole` which accepts a `Qt::ColorRole`, but I am not sure how to use this one as well.

Kindly let me know, what's the simple way to change the background color of a `QComboBox` or `QDoubleSpinBox`?

Answer (score 42, accepted):

Using a `QPalette` isn't guaranteed to work for all styles, because style authors are restricted by the different platforms' guidelines and by the native theme engine.

To make sure your background color will be correct, I would suggest to use the [Qt Style Sheet](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/stylesheet.html). Here is what I did to change the background color of a `QComboBox`:

`myComboBox->setStyleSheet("QComboBox { background-color: blue; }");`

I haven't specifically tried for a `QSpinBox`, but I guess it'll work the same !

Comment: Using a stylesheet for setting the background colour isn't the correct approach, unless you're willing to also style the other sub-controls in the QComboBox (i.e. drop-down and down-arrow). See the note from the Qt documentation: "With complex widgets such as QComboBox and QScrollBar, if one property or sub-control is customized, all the other properties or sub-controls must be customized as well." Link: http://doc.trolltech.com/4.5/stylesheet-customizing.html

Comment: i get white borders at the top and the bottom where the rounded edges are on mac

Answer (score 46):

fhe is generally correct, but doesn't account for the widgets (like spin boxes and buttons/comboboxes) that use a different background role in the palette.  A more general solution would be something like this:

```
QPalette pal = widget.palette();
pal.setColor(widget.backgroundRole(), Qt::blue);
widget.setPalette(pal);
```

Alternatively, you could look into the descriptions of the various palette roles and figure out the one you want, then apply it to the widget containing the others you want changed.  The palette changes should propagate to the children widgets.

Answer (score 14):

Actually, if you look at the Qt docs for QPalette in the case of a QComboBox the background role is probably not what you want.  What you want is:

> **QPalette::Base**  Used mostly as the background color for text entry widgets, but can also be used for other painting - such as the background of combobox drop down lists and toolbar handles. It is usually white or another light color.

So here is the code I am using to set the background color of a combo box I am using to match the color of the widget it is on:

```
QPalette pal = myComboBox->palette();
pal.setColor(QPalette::Base, pal.color(QPalette::Window));
myComboBox->setPalette(pal);
```

Answer (score 11):

Apparently in Qt 4.1 and onwards, you need to set `this->setAutoFillBackground( true );` for the palette to apply the background color.

Comment: this should be a comment

Answer (score 4):

While the previous answers may set the background color for a non-editable `QComboBox`, they do not work for an editable `QComboBox`. For that case, you need to derive the `QLineEdit` widget used for the editing and reset its background.

Here is how I got it to work:

```
    QComboBox *myComboBox = new QComboBox();
    myComboBox->setEditable(true);
    QColor backColor = QColor(246, 230, 230);
    QLineEdit *lineEditor = myComboBox->lineEdit();
    QPalette pal = lineEditor->palette();
    pal.setColor(QPalette::Base, backColor);
    lineEditor->setPalette(pal);
```

Answer (score 3):

Construct a palette that is blue no matter what the actual widget:

```
comboBox->setPalette( QPalette( Qt::blue ) );
```

Answer (score 1):

No previously answers worked for me, but I made a mix of all responses and finally worked on **Qt 5.12**:

```
QPalette pal = ui.widget->palette();
pal.setColor(QPalette::Base, Qt::red);
ui.widget->setPalette(pal);
```

Comment: Nice answer!  Another cool, and more subtle, highlight effect is to use `QPalette::Background` instead of `QPalette::Base`, but with dark colors like magenta or green.

Answer (score 0):

I'd try something like

```
QPalette pal = widget.palette();
pal.setColor(QPalette::Window, Qt::blue);
widget.setPalette(pal);
```

Comment: I tried doing this, but somehow the background color is not getting updated. Any idea what could be the reason. Is there anything else you had assumed..

Comment: What i mean is should i be invoking something like a repaint or anything after doing the setPalette

Comment: I have no QT to test here, but QWidget::update() should force a repaint. Have you tried Jérôme's solution?

Comment: `QPalette::Window` is not the `backgroundRole()` of `QComboBox`, so this code does nothing for a `QComboBox`.

Answer (score -1):

```
comboBox->setPalette( QPalette( Qt::blue ) );
```

Works fine for me!

Comment: I tried this, but mine only works if the QSpinBox is disabled (i.e. if the QSpinBox is enaled, the color back to normal). Any idea?