# PyQt and QtDesigner

Tags: pyqt4, qt-designer

I am trying to implement a LED in PyQt named disLDR1 by trying to change the background color. I am trying to use QPalette to change the BackgroundRole. But what is the equivalent of Qt::red?

Is this the correct way to set the background color or is there any other way?

```
#!/usr/bin/python -d

import sys
from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui
from main import Ui_Form
from PyQt4.QtGui import QPalette

class Top(QtGui.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent = None):
        QtGui.QWidget.__init__(self, parent)
        self.ui = Ui_Form()
        self.ui.setupUi(self)
        for i in 1, 10:
            self.setOff()
            self.setOn()
    def setOff(self):
        self.pal = QPalette(self.ui.disLDR1.palette())
        self.pal.setColor(self.ui.disLDR1.backgroundRole(), <<<RED COLOR>>>)
        self.ui.disLDR1.setPalette(pal)
    def setOn(self):
        self.pal = QPalette(self.ui.disLDR1.palette())
        self.pal.setColor(self.ui.disLDR1.backgroundRole(), <<<GREEN COLOR>>>)
        self.ui.disLDR1.setPalette(pal)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    myapp = Top()
    myapp.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

EDIT: I have been trying to take help from [In Qt, how do I set the background color of a widget like combobox or double spin box?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/177778/in-qt-how-do-i-set-the-background-color-of-a-widget-like-combobox-or-double-spin) but don't know what to substitute for QT::red

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find the list of predefined Qt color objects at [this link](https://web.archive.org/web/20120311010450/https://riverbankcomputing.com/static/Docs/PyQt4/html/qt.html).  In this case you would just need to use `QtCore.Qt.red` and `QtCore.Qt.blue`.  You could also use the [`QColor`](https://web.archive.org/web/20120310203121/https://riverbankcomputing.com/static/Docs/PyQt4/html/qcolor.html) class to generate arbitrary colors.

It's a matter of preference, but I personally think the easiest and most powerful way to go would be to use a [style sheet](https://web.archive.org/web/20110808160655/http://doc.qt.nokia.com/latest/stylesheet.html).