# QMainWindow does not show Qwidgets background

Tags: c++, qt, qwidget, qmainwindow

I have a problem regarding a `QWidget` (custom made) inside a `QMainWindow` (custom made). My problem is that when I add my widget to my window as its central widget using `setCentralWidget()` method, it won't show the widgets background. It's important to show the background correctly.
Here is my `MyWindow.cpp` code:

```
#include "MyMainWindow.h"

MyMainWindow::MyMainWindow(QWidget * parent, Qt::WindowFlags flag) :
        QMainWindow(parent, flag)
{
    this->setFixedSize(1120, 630);
    menu = new MyMenu(this);
//    setting = new MySetting();
//    tutorial = new MyTutorial();
//    game = new MyGame();
    this->setCentralWidget(menu);
    this->show();
}

MyMainWindow::~MyMainWindow()
{
}
```

My `MyMenu.cpp` code:

```
#include "MyMenu.h"

MyMenu::MyMenu(QWidget *parent, Qt::WindowFlags f) :
        QWidget(parent, f)
{
    this->resize(1120, 630);
    this->set_background();
    this->construct_buttons();
    this->construct_menu();
}

MyMenu::~MyMenu()
{
    delete start;
    delete setting;
    delete tutorial;
    delete exit;
    delete buttons;
    delete logo;
    delete menu;
}

void MyMenu::construct_menu()
{
    menu = new QVBoxLayout(this);
    logo = new QLabel(this);
    QPixmap *pixmap = new QPixmap("/home/kahrabian/ClionProjects/Shooter-AP93UT/Contents/logo.png");
    logo->setPixmap(*pixmap);
    logo->setAlignment(Qt::AlignHCenter);
    menu->addWidget(logo);
    menu->addLayout(buttons);
    delete pixmap;
}

void MyMenu::construct_buttons()
{
    buttons = new QHBoxLayout();
    start = new QPushButton("Start", this);
    buttons->addWidget(start);
    setting = new QPushButton("Setting", this);
    buttons->addWidget(setting);
    tutorial = new QPushButton("Tutorial", this);
    buttons->addWidget(tutorial);
    exit = new QPushButton("Exit", this);
    buttons->addWidget(exit);
}

void MyMenu::set_background()
{
    QPalette *palette = new QPalette();
    palette->setBrush(this->backgroundRole(),QBrush(QImage("/home/kahrabian/ClionProjects/Shooter-AP93UT/Contents/background_menu.jpg")));
    this->setPalette(*palette);
    delete palette;
}
```

My `main.cpp` code:

```
#include <QApplication>
#include "MyMenu.h"
#include "MyMainWindow.h"

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    QApplication app (argc, argv);
    MyMainWindow *mainwin = new MyMainWindow();
//    MyMenu *MyMenu = new MyMenu();
//    MyMenu->show();
    return app.exec();
}
```

Can anyone help me with this problem??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/177778/in-qt-how-do-i-set-the-background-color-of-a-widget-like-combobox-or-double-spi).

I would recommend you to use Qt style sheets.

You would need to call something like this:

```
setStyleSheet("image: url(path/to/background/image.png);");
```

on your widget.

Also, you might need to implement `paintEvent()` for widget to accept style sheets. 
I'm usually doing it like this:

```
void MyWidget::paintEvent(QPaintEvent *pe)
{    
    QStyleOption opt;
    opt.init(this);
    QPainter p(this);
    style()->drawPrimitive(QStyle::PE_Widget, &opt, &p, this);

    QWidget::paintEvent(pe);
}
```

Comment: thank you, but this answer does not generate the desired answer, it changes the background but it also changes the buttons shape. can you provide me with somthing similar to implementation that I have used?? it generates the desired answer until I add the widget as a central widget to my MainWindow (I can't understand why)

Comment: I would suggest trying "border-image" or "image" instead of "background-image" in style sheet. Look [here](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/stylesheet-customizing.html#box-model) for more information. Also you could try providing same `paintEvent()` implementation for your `MyMainWindow` class. I can't try your code myself now, although I might be able to do that later today.

Comment: thank you very much, it works fine now. I used "image" instead of "background-image" also I deleted paintEvent(). it works fine without it :-)

Comment: No problem, mate. I'm glad that helps. Also, I have edited my answer according to your response.